# Is it possible to set the theme for an Android Activity using the Theme drop-down in the Graphical Layout editor in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I know how to set the theme for an Application and/or Activity in Android, but I'm wondering if it's possible to change it for an Activity using the Graphical Layout editor in Eclipse 4.2, ADT 20.0.1. No matter what I change the drop-down to, the AppTheme style from styles.xml is always used when I run the app, despite the display preview changing based on what I select. Is it currently not possible because the theme gets set in the AndroidManifest?

[image: Android theme selections in Eclipse Graphical Layout editor]

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drop down box in the GUI is used to see what it looks like, if you want the theme changed then you have to edit the Android Manifest yourself

If you want to edit the theme using a drop down, in one of the tabs in the Android Manifest, I think its "Application" there is an option to change the theme and it has a list of themes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the drop-down in the Manifest editor!

Comment: No problem :D. I hardly use it however, mainly just type the xml by hand but it depends how fast you can type and whether you know the theme you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the theme must be set in the Manifest or in Java.

The drop-down on the layout editor is only there to help debug and test theme issues and whatnot, it doesn't have any effect on your actual app.